# How to run single amazon AMI for three different environments ? like dev qa prod

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, development-environment, production-environment

How to run Single Amazon AMI for three different environments,
while instance provisioning or waiting state i need to pass my own configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get fancy and launch *exactly the same instances*, but add a tag to each instance indicating whether it is Dev/Staging/Prod.

The startup script can examine the tag attached to its EC2 instance and then configure itself accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using linux, see: [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

When launching, pass different user data for different environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CFT, I would suggest mapping during instance provision.